# How can I count "Pass" And "Failed" on table to generate Pivot Table?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

For example, [this is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bPe2.png). The data has "Pass" And "Failed".  How can I count how many pass and failed and generate to Pivot Table.

Comment: Does it have to be a pivot table?  Could you just use another sheet where row 1 has a formula such as `='Sheet1'!A1` and in row 2 have a formula such as `="Pass: "&COUNTIF('Sheet1'!A:A,"Pass")` and in row 3 have a formula such as `="Fail: "&COUNTIF('Sheet1'!A:A,"Fail")`?

Comment: Could you change the `Pass/Fail` to `1/0`, then pivot and SUM?

Comment: @user3240704  still not found any solution. Now i just change to 1/0.. All done.. Thanks..